# Как добавить объект в объект, или объединить

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой код:

```js
var obj = {};
var obj1 = {"id": 7};
var obj2 = {"id": 8};
var obj3 = {"id": 9};

var objOut = {...obj, ...obj1, ...obj2, ...obj3};

console.log(objOut);
```

Хочу чтобы в итоге было так:

```
var objOut = {
  {"id": 7},
  {"id": 8},
  {"id": 9}
}
```

Comment: "Хочу чтобы было так" - так не бывает :(.

Comment: Это нарушает правила синтаксиса JSON.

Comment: @Igor а если "id" сделать уникальный числом?

Comment: Не понял. Они у Вас и так все разные. Что Вы хотите получить? Только правильное.

Comment: тоесть ключ должен быть обязательно разный?

Comment: Какой ключ? В JSON не могут идти две открывающие фигурные скобки подряд.

Comment: @bolatol377, Пожалуйста, не меняй суть вопроса правками - особенно когда это делает полученные ответы нерелевантными. Правки могут только уточнять суть (а совершенно другой желаемый результат - это далеко не уточнение).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JSON не могут идти две открывающие фигурные скобки подряд.

```js
var objOut = {
  {"id": 7},
  {"id": 8},
  {"id": 9}
};
```

---

```js
function together() {
  var res = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) 
    res[i+1] = arguments[i];
  return res;
}

var obj1 = {"id": 7};
var obj2 = {"id": 8};
var obj3 = {"id": 9};

var objOut = together(obj1, obj2, obj3);
console.log(objOut);
```

Но, мне кажется, проще:

```js
var obj1 = {"id": 7};
var obj2 = {"id": 8};
var obj3 = {"id": 9};

var objOut = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
console.log(objOut);
```

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. А если так?

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! В очередной раз сильно помогли, сразу видно что у вас многолетний стаж, не то что у меня 2 месяца всего как начал с js работать))

Comment: @bolatol377 На здоровье. Стаж - дело наживное :).